# looping MediaPlayer using Runnable fails

Tags: java, android

```
try {
        mp.setDataSource(text);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.setVolume(0.4f, 0.4f);

    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IllegalMonitorStateException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

final Handler hlr = new Handler();

   final Runnable looper = new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run()
       {
           if(mp!=null)
           {
               if(mp.isPlaying())
               {
                   mp.stop();
               }
           }

           mp.start();

       }
   };





    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
        {
            hlr.postDelayed(looper, 5000);
        }
    });
```

The above line of code is part of an Alarm Activity , My objective is to loop an Audio file, with a delay of `5000` ms. However, the code doesn't seems to have any effect. Unable to play the audio. What am I doing wrong? Please help me fix this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You don't seem to call `mp.start()` anywere else beside inside the runnable. If that is the case,  `onCompletion(...)` will never be triggered.

Comment: so, how should I fix this in the best way? :)

Comment: Just start the playback, call `hlr.post(looper);` or `mp.start()` when you want to start the looping.

Comment: can you post as an Answer?